# Android:Recurring in paypal

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I am making an app in which i have to implement *recurring payment* in `paypal`.I have implemented paypal but i don't know how to implement recurring payment in paypal in android.
Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: The only way I know to do it is the new feature: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recurring payment is not possible in android .You can only have one time payment or you have to make payment again and again..
Hope this helps..

Comment: It IS possible with PP Mobile Express Checkout and recurring payments.